# Killing abandoned process on Heroku

Tags: heroku

I killed an IRB prompt in a not-so-graceful manner (started with `heroku run irb`), and now I've got a zombie process which I can't seem to kill:

```
Process       State               Command
------------  ------------------  ------------------------------
run.3         up for 2h           irb -r ./init.rb
web.1         up for 0s           thin -p $PORT -e $RACK_ENV -R $HER..
```

I've tried:

- `heroku restart`
- `heroku ps:scale run=0`
- `heroku ps:restart run.3`

Anyone know how I can force quit it?

Answer (score 142, accepted):

I noticed a new `ps:stop` command added to the Heroku command line client a few days ago:
https://github.com/heroku/heroku/commit/a6d9eb7f314bf2c5f162a508e8d764286fb577bb

I'm not sure if that change made it into version 2.9.0 but it would be worth a try.

**Update**

This is now in the [Heroku Toolbelt](http://toolbelt.heroku.com).  Just run:

```
heroku ps:stop <process id from heroku ps>
```

Example:

```
heroku ps:stop run.8729
```

Comment: note if you're looking for a typical Process ID like you might find in *nix terminals (eg 54194), you won't see it. Instead use something like `heroku ps:stop run.3`

Comment: Make sure you check with `heroku ps` that stopping succeeded. The client will accept invalid process ID's and happily report a success. I presumed it worked after using just the number after `run.`, but one needs to include `run.`. So e.g. `heroku ps:stop run.1234` works if you indeed have a process with that name/ID, `heroku ps:stop 1234` doesn't, but is reported as working.

Answer (score 14):

Thanks James!!  I needed to update my Heroku client first, and it worked like a charm.

```
$ sudo gem install heroku

$ heroku ps #to view processes

$ heroku stop <process name here>
```

Answer (score 0):

edit: they've fixed this issue

Heroku doesn't have a way to kill abandoned run.x processes.

But it will be killed automatically after 24 hours.

Comment: annoying huh? I suffered from same thing - 24hr of billing for a terminated process. Not ideal!!

Comment: Yes exactly. If I quit the console and it doesn't terminate, I get punished by 24 hours? Silly, especially since it's obviously doing nothing

Comment: @BasharAbdullah, if you run say a Rails console, you may sit there for a few minutes in between commands. What would you expect Heroku to do? Kill any process that goes idle for a few seconds/minutes/hours? That would get annoying for rails console processes when you're trying to debug.

Comment: @WattsInABox In your scenario yes, but we're talking about closing the terminal but the connection remains hanging, when they should detect connection was terminated and kill the process. The issue is resolved now by Heroku.

Comment: @WattsInABox no problem at all.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else is struggling with killing using something like:

```
heroku run ps:stop run.789
```

Killing by id worked for me:

```
heroku ps:kill 61ff0687-eaf4-4299-9c65-f0b22af7ec67
```

I got the id using the platform api list dynos - https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/platform-api-reference#dyno-list

Worked for a detached one-off that was abandoned.